# Optimal Cutoff Point for max sum of sensitivity and specificity

Tags: probability, prediction, glm, threshold

I would like to calculate the sensitivity-specificity sum maximization threshold (Youden Index) for my glm model:

`model = glm(present ~ Summer_precipitation + Summer_temperature + Frost_days + Snowcover_days + Forest_presence + Population_density + Tick_density + Vaccination_coverage, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = tbe_data)`

I calculated predicted probabilities for the model. "Weather data" is a stacked raster file of all the covariate rasters listed in the model above.

#create predictions based on weather data

`predictions=predict(weather_data,model,type="response")`

#plot predictions

`plot(predictions)`

How can I now calculate the optimal probability cutoff point from the model? I would use the "cutpointr" function but don't know how to adapt the code to my situation

Answer (score 0):

I use R package `dismo` for many of my modelling evaluations. You can first calculate the perfect `threshold()` and then `evaluate()` using excatly this threshold.